# Existence of a limit ..

Tags: calculus, limits

Does  $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$  exist or not?, where $f(x)= \frac{[x]}{x}$.

I know what is $[x]$. Here $[x]$ denotes the greatest integer not greater than $x$.

Please someone give some hints or solution.

Comment: You know what $[x]$ is, but we don't know what notation you're using.  Please explain what $[x]$ is.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom [x] is generally used for grestest integer function.

Comment: From right side is 0 and from left side is infinity so it doesn't

Comment: @mathiu_lady also, what have you tried? Where exactly do you get stuck?

Comment: What are $f(0.00000001)$ and $f(-0.00000001)$ ?

Comment: The answer can be yes or no, depending on $[x]$.

Comment: @ATHARVA $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is generally used for the greatest integer function. $[x]$ is just $x$ in parentheses, which generally has no particular meaning.

Comment: apparanetly the limit does not exist. Limit from left is inifinity and limit from right is zero. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x-%3E0+floor(x)%2Fx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To evaluate $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)$  we have to evaluate both the left hand limit as well as the right hand limit.

We can see that

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-}\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x}$$

$$= \frac{-1}{-x} \rightarrow \frac{1}{0}= \infty$$

Whereas the right hand limit evaluates as $ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x)$

$$=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x}$$

$$= lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{0}{x}$$

$$=0$$

Since the left hand limit is not equal to the right hand limit we can conclude that the above function's limit does not exist when $x \rightarrow 0$

Answer (score 5):

[In order for this limit to exist, the limit as approached from the left and the limit as approached from the right must both exist and be equal to each other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Existence_and_one-sided_limits).

From the left, $x$ is a very small negative number going to $0$, and $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is $-1$. This means that the limit from the left is $+\infty$. A limit from the left can be written with a superscript minus sign:
$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^{-}} \displaystyle\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x} = \infty$$

From the right, $x$ is a very small positive number going to $0$, and $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is $0$. This means that the limit from the right is $0$. A limit from the right can be written with a superscript plus sign:

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^{+}} \displaystyle\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x} = 0$$

Since these two results do not agree, the limit of $f(x)$, as $x\to0$, does not exist.